# LDAP sizelimit exceeded despite a high sizelimit

Tags: openldap

I have the problem "LDAP sizelimit exceeded" (I know it has been discussed here several times). Unfortunately, the previous solutions here and on other sites did not help.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the package slapd. I created the file `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf` and wrote `sizelimit 10000` in it. In `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif` I added the entry accordingly.

```
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
olcLogLevel: None
olcPidFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
olcToolThreads: 1
olcSizeLimit: 10000
structuralObjectClass: olcGlobal
entryUUID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20160825143715Z
entryCSN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20160905182032Z
```

After restarting the service, the error message appears again. What do I have to adjust to get more than 500 entries?

Answer (score 0):

`olcSizeLimit` only applys to `dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config`, put it there and it should do what you want.

You're supposed to use `ldapmodify` to change the `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/` files, and doing so for most interactions doesn't require restarting `slapd` for those changes to take effect. It also keeps the file checksums correct, if your slapd is using them.

You could get more granular with `olcLimits` on the appropriate db. (More detail in `slapd-config(5)`.)